# Post request with body into a model

Tags: post, model

I had to implement it using javascript.

I have this class:

```
Public Class RecommendedJobsData
    Public Property searchedJobsList As List(Of JobInfo)
    Public Property jobFromStorage As JobInfo
    Public Property totalJobsCount As Integer
    Public Property adType As AdType

    Public Sub New() ' default constructor

    End Sub

    ' constructor with parameters
    Public Sub New(searchedJobsList As List(Of JobInfo), jobFromStorage As JobInfo, totalJobsCount As Integer, adType As AdType)
        Me.searchedJobsList = searchedJobsList
        Me.jobFromStorage = jobFromStorage
        Me.totalJobsCount = totalJobsCount
        Me.adType = adType
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to send a post request to this function:

```
<JsonpFilter()>
Public Function GetToken(header As RequestHeader, body As RecommendedJobsData) As String

    Return String.Empty

End Function
```

So I used javascript:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(apiParams);
```

The header is passed fine, but the body is not..

It enters the default constructor instead of the constructor that gets parameters, and then, there are null values in the body object of `GetToken` function.

This is apiParams:

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the content-type to be:

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

And then I changed the send function:

```
http.send(JSON.stringify(apiParams));
```

And the most important thing is:

`<FromBody()>` attribute in GetToken function:

```
Public Function GetToken(header As RequestHeader, 
<FromBody()> body As RecommendedJobsData)
```

Note to add a reference to system.web.http.